# match array to multiple regex (from array)

Tags: powershell

I have an array with Strings, let´s say

```
$data = @(
"Haus",
"Maus",
"Laus",
"Schnitzel",
"Elefant"
)
```

I want to check it against multiple Regex from an array.

```
$regexChecks = @(
".*aus.*",
".*fant.*"
)
```

I tried something like this

```
$test = $data |? {$regexChecks -notmatch $_}

Write-Host $test
```

I expect only the String "Schnitzel" as output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can put the regex as a string. This would only return `Schnitzel`

```
$data = @(
"Haus",
"Maus",
"Laus",
"Schnitzel",
"Elefant"
)

$Regex = '.*Schnitzel.*'

$test = $data | ? { $_ -match $Regex }

Write-Host $test
```

if you want to check more than one regex, use `|` to seperate them

This would output `Schnitzel` and `Maus`

```
$Regex = '.*Schnitzel.*|.*Maus.*'
```

This would return `Schnitzel`, `Maus`, `Laus` and `Haus`

```
$Regex = '.*Schnitzel.*|.*aus.*'
```

**EDIT**:

You can also have a regex array, and join them with `|`:

```
$RegexArray = @(
    '.*Schnitzel.*',
    '.*Maus.*'
)

$Regex = $RegexArray -join '|'

$test = $data | ? { $_ -match $Regex }
```

Comment: ah i was maybe a bit unclear, this example is oversimplifyed. I have a high amount of regex i want to check and store in an array... Oh now i see your edit that should do the trick!

Comment: @SteffenBauer I hope so, otherwise feel free to ask. I'm craving a Schnitzel now

Answer (score 5):

Regular expression matches are much slower operations that literal comparisons (`-eq`) or even wildcard matches (`-like`), so you should reduce the number of comparisons as much as possible. Since you have an array of regular expressions you can simply merge them into a single one like this:

```
$regexChecks = '.*aus.*', '.*fant.*'
$re = $regexChecks -join '|'
```

If you want multiple literal strings matched you can tell PowerShell to escape them first (just in case they contain special characters like dots, square brackets, etc.):

```
$re = ($regexChecks | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
```

Also, you don't need to add leading and trailing `.*` to your expressions, because regular expressions aren't anchored by default. Just leave them out.

```
$regexChecks = 'aus', 'fant'
$re = ($regexChecks | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
```

You also don't need `Where-Object` or `ForEach-Object` to enumerate the elements of an array, because PowerShell operators work as enumerators themselves. Simply use the operator on the array directly:

```
$test = $data -match $re
```

Comment: +1 for having an answer with more knowledge than mine. didn't know about omitting the `.*` and also didn't consider `escape`. nice!